# How to pick data of the same IDs without repetition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I pick data of same IDs without any repetition?

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @YourTable
SELECT 123, 'James Hill'

INSERT INTO @YourTable
SELECT 123, 'Hill, James'

INSERT INTO @YourTable
SELECT 234, 'Doe, Mary Jane'

INSERT INTO @YourTable
SELECT 234, 'Doe, Mary Jane D.'

INSERT INTO @YourTable
SELECT 234, 'Doe, Mary Jane'

FROM @yourTable
WHERE cast_id IN (
    SELECT Name
    FROM @yorTable
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)";
```

What is a way to handle my data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking entirely but look into DISTINCT, it might solve your issue.

Comment: Which name you wants to keep from two almost similar name for the same id like - 123? Anyone from the name will be OK for you?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of the names from the redundant names is acceptable, you can achieve your desired results by the following script:

```
SELECT ID,MAX(Name)
FROM @YourTable
GROUP BY ID
```